# laravel Liveware.emit not listening in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-livewire

From my resources \views\streets.blade.php, I want to click a button to fire an event and change the variable value:

```
        <x-jet-button class="ml-3" wire:click="window.livewire.emit('updateVariable', 1)" id="aaa">
        {{ __('aaa') }}
        </x-jet-button>
<script>

    //@ts-ignore
    document.getElementById('aaa').addEventListener('click', () => {
        window.livewire.emit('updateVariable', PRG = 1);
    });
    function loadXMLDoc() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("child").innerHTML =
                    this.response;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", "overview", true);
        xhttp.send();
    }
     setInterval(function () {
         loadXMLDoc();
     }, 1000);

    window.onload = loadXMLDoc;
</script>
```

in Http\Livewire\Overview.php, it look's like, it's not listening:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;

class Overview extends Component
{
    public $PRG;
    protected $listeners = ['updateVariable'];
    public function mount()
    {
        $this->PRG = 0;  // Or any other default value you need
    }

    public function updateVariable()
    {
        $this->PRG = 1;
    }

    public function render(): View
    {
        return view('livewire.overview');
    }
}
```

Finally in resources\views\livewire\overview.blade.php, I wish to change the led color, but it is still showing as default green color:

```
<x-jet-button class="ml-3" wire:click="updateVariable" wire:loading.attr="disabled">
                    {{ __('aaa') }}
                </x-jet-button>
<div id="led" class="{{ $PRG == 0 ? 'greenLed' : 'redLed' }} led col"></div>
```

Comment: I assume you've read [the docs](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events#from-template). Is everything in one root div? Is your `@livewireStyles` and `@livewireScripts` placed properly?

Comment: @Yinci `@livewireStyles` and `@livewireScripts` placed at resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php, I don't understand if it mean's in one root div

Comment: Read https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting#root-element-issues